# Creating infinite background scroll right to left

Tags: swift, uiview, uiviewanimation

I am trying to create an animation to create an illusion of moving object. So the object will stay at the same position but the background image view which is wider than screen width will move infinitely. The code I have doesn't work very smooth.

```
    let backgroundView = UIView()
    backgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    backgroundView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 120, width: 50, height: 50)
    self.view.addSubview(backgroundView)
    let options = UIViewAnimationOptions.Repeat | UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveLinear

    UIView.animateWithDuration(2.0, delay: 0.0, options: options, animations: {
        backgroundView.frame = CGRect(x: 420, y: 120, width: 50, height: 50)
        }, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Updated answer:**

To animate a [background image](https://dribbble.com/shots/1733275-Montage-Delivery-Truck) like you've mentioned in your comment, one way would be to create a seamless pattern for your background image and move it across the screen. For example, Move image1 across screen, follow it with image2, move image1 back to original position, move image2 back to original position, repeat. There's probably an easier way to do this depending on what you're actually going to be using this for, but this is just one example. I've made a [simple background pattern](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B0xAr.jpg) for this example, feel free to use it.

```
func animateBackground() {
    let animationOptions = UIViewAnimationOptions.Repeat | UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveLinear
    let backgroundImage = UIImage(named:"backgroundPattern.jpg")!
    var amountToKeepImageSquare = backgroundImage.size.height - self.view.frame.size.height

    // UIImageView 1
    var backgroundImageView1 = UIImageView(image: backgroundImage)
    backgroundImageView1.frame = CGRect(x: self.view.frame.origin.x, y: self.view.frame.origin.y, width: backgroundImage.size.width - amountToKeepImageSquare, height: self.view.frame.size.height)
    self.view.addSubview(backgroundImageView1)

    // UIImageView 2
    var backgroundImageView2 = UIImageView(image: backgroundImage)
    backgroundImageView2.frame = CGRect(x: backgroundImageView1.frame.size.width, y: self.view.frame.origin.y, width: backgroundImage.size.width - amountToKeepImageSquare, height: self.view.frame.height)
    self.view.addSubview(backgroundImageView2)

    // Animate background
    UIView.animateWithDuration(6.0, delay: 0.0, options: animationOptions, animations: {
        backgroundImageView1.frame = CGRectOffset(backgroundImageView1.frame, -1 * backgroundImageView1.frame.size.width, 0.0)
        backgroundImageView2.frame = CGRectOffset(backgroundImageView2.frame, -1 * backgroundImageView2.frame.size.width, 0.0)
        }, completion: nil)

    // Have something in the foreground look like its moving
    var square = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))
    square.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: self.view.frame.origin.x + 25, y: self.view.frame.size.height - 75)
    square.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()
    self.view.addSubview(square)

    // Animate foreground
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.5, delay: 0, options: animationOptions, animations: {
        square.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(33)
        }, completion: nil)
}
```

You'll end up with an animation like this:

[image: animatedBackground]

**Original answer:**

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to achieve, but from what I can gather you'd like your view to not *jump* back to its starting position when it repeats each animation. You can achieve this by setting your `UIView`'s starting point off the left side of the view and its ending point off the right side of the view.

```
func animateSquare() {
    // Create our square with size of 50x50
    var square = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: self.view.frame.height / 2, width: 50, height: 50))
    // Set its origin just off the left of the screen so it is not visible
    square.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 0 - square.frame.size.width, y: self.view.frame.height / 2)
    square.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    self.view.addSubview(square)

    // Setup animation and repeat
    let animationOptions = UIViewAnimationOptions.Repeat | UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveLinear
    UIView.animateWithDuration(2.0, delay: 0, options: animationOptions, animations: {
        // Offset our square's frame by the width of the view + the width of the square
        // This way it moves off the screen to the right completely
        square.frame = CGRectOffset(square.frame, self.view.frame.width + square.frame.width, 0.0)
        }, completion: nil)
}
```

You'll end up with an animation like this:

[image: animatedSquare]

Comment: Sorry my code was moving from left to right instead of opposite. I am trying to achieve some kind of animations like https://dribbble.com/shots/1733275-Montage-Delivery-Truck As you can see, it is moving background and foreground to create some animation. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: @Meanteacher I've updated my answer to give you an example of how to achieve what you've mentioned in your comment. More would have to be done to make it *polished* but the logic is all the same.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It will really help me a lot. I want to use this for a refresh control. Therefore I will change the size etc. However your answer really put me on the right track. I appreciate it again sir.

Answer (score 2):

For Swift 5.0+, use the below function.

```
func animateBackground()
{
    let backgroundImage = UIImage(named:"bgImage")!

    // UIImageView 1
    let backgroundImageView1 = UIImageView(image: backgroundImage)
    backgroundImageView1.frame = CGRect(x: self.view.frame.origin.x, y: self.view.frame.origin.y, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height)
    backgroundImageView1.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    self.view.addSubview(backgroundImageView1)

    // UIImageView 2
    let backgroundImageView2 = UIImageView(image: backgroundImage)
    backgroundImageView2.frame = CGRect(x: self.view.frame.size.width, y: self.view.frame.origin.y, width: self.view.frame.size.width, height: self.view.frame.height)
    backgroundImageView2.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    self.view.addSubview(backgroundImageView2)

    // Animate background
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 6.0, delay: 0.0, options: [.repeat, .curveLinear], animations: {
        backgroundImageView1.frame = backgroundImageView1.frame.offsetBy(dx: -1 * backgroundImageView1.frame.size.width, dy: 0.0)
        backgroundImageView2.frame = backgroundImageView2.frame.offsetBy(dx: -1 * backgroundImageView2.frame.size.width, dy: 0.0)
        }, completion: nil)
}
```